# Why p-values are different

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a data of total number of mutations and fraction of mutations in each patient for three groups of patients

I want to see if these three groups are different in terms of total number of mutations and fraction of mutations

Like this

```
> head(Responders[1:4,1:7])
   Tumor_Sample_Barcode  DEL  INS   SNP MNP total   Response
1:    LP6008337-DNA_H06  927  773 40756   0 42456 Responders
2:    LP6008334-DNA_D02 1049  799 31009   0 32857 Responders
3:    LP6008460-DNA_G03 1022 1176 30285   2 32485 Responders
4:    LP6005334-DNA_H01 1308 1381 28160   0 30849 Responders
>
```

But t test and wilcox test give different p values, then I should use which of these tests?

Comment: Those two tests address very different hypotheses.  You might start by deciding which hypothesis you are interested in.  But also, because the *t*  test makes certain assumptions for the *p* value to be accurate, you might assess if your data would reasonably meet these assumptions.

Comment: Why would you imagine different tests would give the same p-values? They see the information in the samples quite differently. Rather than throw a bunch of tests at the same data (perhaps leaving yourself open to charges of seeing what will stick), first figure out exactly what you're trying to find out (what's the precise research question), what kinds of things your variables are (measurements, times, percentages, counts, etc), and what you're prepared to assume about them.

Comment: Thank you. My assumption is that the number of mutations (raw count) could be different between different groups.